# How to copy resource (any content) files to output folder when NUnit's shadow copying is turned on?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Of course there is an option to turn it off (by default it is on.) However I like to be able to make incremental changes to the DLL while a copy of NUnit GUI is up.

However I couldn't find much documentation for this feature (apart from [the need](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.dotnet.nunit.devel/2004-04/msg00005.html))
So the problem is like this

With Shadow copy enabled in NUnit,
my SUT (Dll) invokes an executable (also in the output folder ; via references). Now this executable needs certain configuration/modifier files to be in the same folder as the executable. How do I ensure that my reference modifier files are reachable by the executable during the test ?

Does NUnit shadow copy just the SUT dll or all the linked/referenced dlls/execs ? What do I need to do in the test setup such that any supporting files for the SUT are copied correctly?

I see that

- executingAssembly.Codebase gives me the original output folder
- executingAssembly.Location gives me the shadow copy folder.

I'm not sure if I am being lucid here - let me know if I need to update

Answer (score 4):

The real issue is usually finding where they are during the tests.

Use this instead of `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`:

```
string exeDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath);
```

See [Trouble with NUnit when determining the assembly's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336068/trouble-with-nunit-when-determining-the-assemblys-directory)

Comment: 2 years later I can't even recollect why I posted this. Assembly.Codebase based lookups usually work for me. Location doesn't because NUnit copies the dlls to obscure paths but not the associated files